# Enabling Cross Domain ASP.net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web, Version 12.0.30501.00 Update 2. I have a solution with 2 project in it, one is a web api, and the second is an MVC project intended for for the views. I have create a simple web api returning httpresponsemessage and I can go in fiddler and I will see the json response. However in my second project when attempting to call  through ajax I received a cross domain error.

The solution I try to follow is this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api. However when installing `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors -pre -project WebService` in the console manager I received an error so I used this line instead. `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` then I try to the next step which is `config.EnableCors();` its state that

```
'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'EnableCors' and no extension method 'EnableCors' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I am not sure what to afterward, I also try to add `using System.Web.Http.Cors;` but state that the namespace does not exists. This visual studio was downloaded about 3 weeks ago, I feel this feature should not be hard to install as it fully supported, is there something that i am missing?

Comment: What is the error that you get in Package Manager? Have you tried installing this NuGet package via GUI?

Comment: what .NET version are you running?

Comment: The framework is 4.5.50938 and no i have not try to install it throug nuget via gui, and it does get installed

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You should install a  Nuget package **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors**

From the menu in visual studio, go to Management Packages, and then type in the name of the package

**Note:**
To install from *Package Manager Console*, use `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`

Comment: I had to install it from the command line as It wouldn't show in the list.

Comment: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

Comment: And then: using System.Web.Http.Cors

Answer (score 11):

install a Nuget package `"Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" (version="5.1.0")

Add following line in your WebApiConfig.cs file

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```