# Add a custom header to a .NET web service which returns a custom object, not a Request type object

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a web service written in .NET where the controller methods look like this:

```
[Route("upload/")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ApiResponse<Form12_Attachement>> UploadFile()
    {

    }
```

The objects called `ApiResponse` and `Form12_Attachment` are custom classes written by me and containing a few `string` members.

I need to add a custom header to the response (namely, allow cross-site scripting with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`).

I know how to add a custom header to the webservice when it returns a `System.Net.Request` type object:

```
protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
{
  System.Net.WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
  request.Headers.Add("myheader", "myheader_value");
  return request;
}
```

However, my web service returns a custom class. In this case, how can I add custom headers to the response?

Here's a [solution](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) that I found: add this into the `WebApiConfig.Register()` but it didn't work:

```
        config.EnableCors();
```

It doesn't work because my `HttpConfiguration` object doesn't have the EnableCors method.

Comment: Did you try that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23746034/enabling-cross-domain-asp-net-web-api ?

Comment: Thanks! I've marked my question as a duplicate.